# How to programmatically add lines to rdlc report in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, reporting-services, rdlc

I am designing an Estimate/Quote System report using RDLC, WinForms, C# in Visual Studio 2012. The Estimate could span from 1 to N pages. I am using Tablix to show the Estimate details (line items) in the Report Body. An Estimate details may contain 1 to N line items and the description field could wrap text in a long description.

As per the design requirement the Tablix Columns need to be separated by Visible Vertical Lines when the report is viewed, printed or exported. These lines need to start at the top near the Tablix Header and run to the end of the page i.e. they cover the Report Body from top to bottom. The Body part of the Invoice looks something like this:

[image]

I tried using boarders on the tablix but it doesn't fill the whole body of the report if there are not enough items.  Also since one item is not always equal to one row on the report (because of the description field wrapping) I can't the rows and just add blank ones to fill the space between the body and the footer.

So I'm looking for a way to solve this frustrating issue, which I would have thought would be easy for a report tool to do.  :(

I have the idea to draw lines (maybe rectangles) on the form which I could define in code instead of dragging and dropping on the rdlc designer.  I'm open to other solutions as well and all suggestions are appreciated.

From a very frustrated developer!

Answer (score 0):

You can use rectangles or List control. Check out this discussion, these is an example you can download with List control:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/1ae5ac3e-1a78-4474-a837-daf59d890467/how-to-extend-a-table-till-the-end-of-the-page-plzz-its-urgent?forum=sqlreportingservices

Comment: Thanks for the link!  I'll work with it this afternoon (AST timezone) and let you know how I made out.